# AWS cloudFormation Template for QuickSight

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am trying to make the cloudFormation template for the following architecture/process/data pipeline:

1. DynamoDB has some data which is brought into Glue database using Glue crawler
2. after the data is is brought into Glue database it is transferred to an S3 bucket using Glue ETL job.
3. finally a json file is uploaded to the Quicksight which creates a dataset.

- I have made everything manually using the console and it works fine but I want to make this data pipeline into a cloudFormation template so it can be easily deployed.

Since I am a beginner in AWS cloudFormation and couldn't find a good template/example online, i will appreciate if you can help me out or share resources that might help.

( I am currently using the official documentation )